# Show the user-defined functions and procedures in the database in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, function, procedure, user-defined

Trying to find out the stored functions and procedures on PostgreSQL. I found some of the solutions where "join" has been used. I am looking for an optimal solution/command to it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If there is a command i really not know.
I also use the join solution between pg_catalog.pg_proc and pg_catalog.pg_namespace for example, to list all the functions in one schema.

You can play with the join to get what you need.
This query for example will provide you the commands to change the owner for all the functions on a schema:

```
SELECT 'ALTER FUNCTION '
            || quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' 
            || quote_ident(p.proname) || '(' 
            || pg_catalog.pg_get_function_identity_arguments(p.oid)
            || ') OWNER TO owner_usr;' AS command
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace 
WHERE  n.nspname = 'your_schema';
```

And this one should list you all your user defined functions :

```
SELECT   quote_ident(n.nspname) as schema , quote_ident(p.proname) as function 
FROM   pg_catalog.pg_proc p
JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace 
WHERE  n.nspname not like 'pg%'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe the last line of code would better be modified to: `WHERE  n.nspname not like 'pg_%'` (adding an underscore). Still not completely safe, but much safer already.

Answer (score 19):

You can get functions using meta command

```
\df
```

Comment: Is there a meta command to dump the configuration of a function? Edit: nvm, you can use ' \sf [ function_name ]'

Comment: You might have to supply the db or schema to make this work:
\df <schema> , or \df <schema>.*, so like \df my_db.*

Answer (score 1):

This can show all user-defined functions and procedures in the current database:

```
\df
```

*Use `p` to show all user-defined procedures in the current database:

```
\dfp
```

*Use `S` to show all user-defined and system functions and procedures in the current database:

```
\dfS
```

*Use `+` to show all user-defined functions and procedures in the current database in detail:

```
\df+
```

*You can use `p`, `S` and `+` together to show all user-defined and system procedures in the current database in detail:

```
\dfpS+
```

And, you can show all user-defined and system functions and procedures in the current database with [information_schema.routines](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/infoschema-routines.html) and [pg_proc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html) as shown below:

```sql
SELECT routine_name FROM information_schema.routines;
```

```sql
SELECT proname FROM pg_proc;
```

*There is no way to show all user-defined (and system) functions and procedures in all databases at once.